# Запятая перед "почти"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "почти" в следующем предложении?
Туманная дымка и тишина лежащего внизу луга отправили меня в знакомое почти невесомое состояние. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второе определение обособляется, так как имеет уточняющее значение:

*Туманная дымка и тишина лежащего внизу луга отправили меня в знакомое,  **почти невесомое,**  состояние.*

Розенталь, п.4. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118

Их сопровождал небольшой плотненький человечек с флегматичным, **почти заспанным,** лицом (Т.);

Comment: Спасибо. А если бы не было слова "почти", то запятая не ставилась бы, как при неоднородных определениях?

Comment: Да, эти определения были бы неоднородными (без запятой). А вот у Розенталя его определения были бы однородными, так как значение у них сближенное (флегматичным, заспанным лицом)